# Convert array of objects with parent / child relationships to array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I have a problem transforming an array of objects to another array of nested objects. How can I transform `table` to look like `transformedTable` in the example code below?

Input data:

```
const table = [
  {id: 1, isMain: null, parentId: null, name:"john"},
  {id: 2, isMain: true, parentId: null, name:"sam"},
  {id: 3, isMain: null, parentId: 2, name:"samantha"},
  {id: 4, isMain: true, parentId: null, name:"kate"},
  {id: 5, isMain: true, parentId: 4, name:"jonathan"},
  {id: 6, isMain: null, parentId: 4, name:"walter"},
  {id: 7, isMain: null, parentId: 5, name:"clara"}
]
```

I want to transform the data above to something like this:

```
transformedTable = [{
    id: 1,
    isMain: null,
    parentId: null,
    name: "john"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isMain: true,
    parentId: null,
    name: "sam",
    kids: [{
      id: 3,
      isMain: null,
      parentId: 2,
      name: "samantha"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isMain: true,
    parentId: null,
    name: "kate",
    kids: [{
        id: 5,
        isMain: true,
        parentId: 4,
        name: "jonathan",
        kids: [{
          id: 7,
          isMain: null,
          parentId: 5,
          name: "clara"
        }]
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        isMain: null,
        parentId: 4,
        name: "walter"
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Just iterate through the array and form the new one.

Comment: i know it but how/?? position on object can be shuffled

Comment: Then sort it first?

Comment: Any updates on this? There is an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest a couple of loops to compare each object and add the "kids" property where needed. Then, filter the resulting array to leave just the ultimate parents (which contain all the nested children). See working snippet below:

```js
const table = [{ id: 1, isMain: null, parentId: null, name:"john" }, { id: 2, isMain: true, parentId: null, name:"sam" }, { id: 3, isMain: null, parentId: 2, name:"samantha" }, { id: 4, isMain: true, parentId: null, name:"kate" }, { id: 5, isMain: true, parentId: 4, name:"jonathan" }, { id: 6, isMain: null, parentId: 4, name:"walter" }, { id: 7, isMain: null, parentId: 5, name:"clara" }];
const kid = (p, c) => {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty('kids')) {
    p.kids.push(c);
  } else {
    p.kids = [c];
  }  
};

for (let i = 0; i < table.length - 1; i++) {
  const a = table[i];
  for (let j = i + 1; j < table.length; j++) {
    const b = table[j];
    if (a.id === b.parentId) {
      kid(a, b);
    } else if (b.id === a.parentId) {
      kid(b, a);
    }
  }
}

const result = table.filter((x) => !x.parentId);
console.log(result);
```